# Express запрос API

Tags: express

Есть приложение работающее на express мне необходимо сделать запрос на API (на другой порт) получить данные и записать в localStorage, как лучше всего это сделать какие практики лучшие?

Answer (score 0):

Сервер не имеет прямого доступа к записи/чтению localStorage, работать с ним можно только из клиентской части приложения, работающей непосредственно в браузере.

> Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never transferred to the server.

Перевод:

> В отличие от Cookies, [у localStorage] лимит объема данных выше (как минимум 5Мб), и информация никогда не может быть передана на сервер [имеется в виду напрямую, по инициативе сервера].

[Источник](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

В итоге, записать информацию из express-приложения вы можете только в Cookie, и только потом сохранить ее в localStorage, прочитав от туда. Либо послать Ajax-запрос с клиентской части, и получив ответ, сохранить его в localStorage.

Comment: В принципе можно открыть доступ к базе данных из Express, но меня как то это смущает. Нормально ли это?

Comment: Может стоит прикрутить Redis?